# Always show Scrollbar in mcustomscrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I'm currently using mcustomscrollbar which is a jquery free plugin. Is there a possible way that this plug in should always show the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2):

You might of meant that you want the scroll bar to always be visible, even when the scrollable area's content is less than the viewport part of the container. I reached this question when searching for an answer to this situation. 
The answer is to add `alwaysShowScrollbar` to the configuration object of mCustomScrollbar.

From the documentation:

> alwaysShowScrollbar: integer  - 
>       Always keep scrollbar(s) visible, even when there’s nothing to scroll.
>
> ```
>     alwaysShowScrollbar: 0 – disable (default)
>     alwaysShowScrollbar: 1 – keep dragger rail visible
>     alwaysShowScrollbar: 2 – keep all scrollbar components (dragger, rail, buttons etc.) visible
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar should be visible by default unless you're using **[autoHideScrollbar: true](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#configuration-section)** configuration

Besides that, you can also try using this css:

```
.mCustomScrollBox>.mCSB_scrollTools {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: when an element don't have a scroll yet scroll bar is not visible but when i re-size it until the smallest i could. it shows the scroll bar i want to have the element to have a scroll bar even though it doesn't reach its limit to have a scroll bar. is there a possible way?